# Is it possible to extract a large file using Truezip in java?

Tags: truezip

```
import java.io.IOException;
import utils.myDate;
import utils.myLog;
import de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TArchiveDetector;
import de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile;

public class Main 
{
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Extract(new String("C:/Documents and Settings/mitracomm/My Documents/Downloads/JAR"), new String("D:/Source/Extract Result") , "");     
}

private static void Extract(String src, String dst, String incPath)
{
    TFile srcFile = new TFile(src + "/" + incPath);
    TFile dstFile = new TFile(dst);

    try {
        TFile.cp_rp(srcFile, dstFile, TArchiveDetector.ALL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        myLog.add(myDate.today("yyyyMMdd") + ".log", "error", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Will the above code work with a large archive?  Also, how can I extract every archive in a directory without having to fill the `incPath` or specify archives' name?  I have tried to do this but I end up with copies of all the archives from origin directory and not extracted files.

Comment: I have got this error on console" [13-12-2011 09:46:21][error] D:\Source\Extract Result (cannot set last modification time)

Comment: You are probably running Windows and concurrently accessing the directory. Windows doesn't like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is principally OK, but I'ld use:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Extract(new String("C:/Documents and Settings/mitracomm/My Documents/Downloads/JAR"), new String("D:/Source/Extract Result") , "");        
    }

    private static void Extract(String src, String dst, String incPath) {
        TFile srcFile = new TFile(src, incPath);
        TFile dstFile = new TFile(dst);
        try {
            TFile.cp_rp(srcFile, dstFile, TArchiveDetector.NULL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // I don't like logging for this purpose, but if you must...
            myLog.add(myDate.today("yyyyMMdd") + ".log", "error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you really want three arguments for the Extract method, though.

And finally, yes TrueZIP handles ZIP files beyond 4GB size correctly.

Comment: P.S.: You can find more examples when using the Maven archetype of the project: http://truezip.java.net/kick-start/index.html

Comment: I have tried your code above. But I still have got only just copy of archives not already extracted files. Is the TArchivedetector.NULL (or .ALL) influence the program?

Comment: You need to make sure that the respective archive driver JARs are on your class path, e.g. The JAR for TrueZIP Driver ZIP. See also here: http://truezip.java.net/faq.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I already import the TrueZIP on the program. Have you another guess?

Comment: I don't mean an import statement, I mean composing your class path so that it contains the JAR of the module TrueZIP Driver ZIP. This is usually configured in your POM if you use Maven.

Comment: In order to check your class path setup at compile time, try this: http://truezip.java.net/faq.html#filterTArchiveDetector

Comment: Finally, please make sure to use TrueZIP 7.4.3. It fixes a bug in the ZIP64 implementation.

Comment: I am also getting the same problem. The above code just copy and paste Example.csv.gz

Comment: But the above code works with .zip file. I am using language scala and SBT for dependency management. I thought truezip can work with .gz also but may be I too naive to make it work with .gz

Comment: @RidhwanImad To make it work with .zip please import this jar/maven/sbt     http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.schlichtherle.truezip/truezip-swing/7.7.9